# How can I build an accordion without Javascript using the Field Group module?

Tags: 8

I'm using the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group/) module to make accordions on my site, but it loads JQuery and slows the page down. Is there a way to do this without JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can [use the HTML 5 details tag](https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/building-accordions-html5-details-tag-no-javascript-needed).

On the content type display administration page, create a field group.

For the **Format**, chose `HTML element`.

For **Field group label**, enter the text you want to show to click to display the rest of the text.

For the **Element**, enter `details`.

For **Show Label**, select Yes.

For **Label element**, enter `summary`.

To style with CSS, add extra CSS classes as needed.